Is (or can be) category theory used for inferring classification results?
There is category of groups and there is classification theorem of finite simple groups. There is category of topological spaces and the topological spaces can be classified by topological invariants.
My question is - are there ways and examples how the category theory is (or can be) used for the getting the classifications results (theorems) for the objects for which the category can be formed?
My question is intentionally wide - if I can get just one example, then I can myself dig deeper into matter and try to apply such ideas in the fields that are close to me (higher order logic, homotopy type theory and their model theories (for whom some may say that they don't exist)).

Please clarify what you mean by "classification." The one example you give is a good start, but "classification" really is an informal term and you should tell us what counts as a classification and what not. Is splitting up $\mathrm{Top}$ into the class of all one-point spaces and all spaces of cardinality not equal to one a classification? Is the statement that vector bundles over a nice base space of a given dimension are in natural bijection to homotopy classes of maps out of the base into a certain space a classification?

@BenSteffan There is already on answer which I am gradually digesting. But - referring to your concern - we can consider the category Top (of topological spaces) and the collation of facts about topological invariants as the classification result. So - how such result can be seen from the categorical perspective and can it be deduced by the categorical tools. E.g. many topological invariants can be considered as functors from Top in category of groups or other categories. E.g. functor that assigns homotopy groups of chains of homology groups. So... Can this be discovered/recast categorically?

@BenSteffan E.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870818303062 is nice article about forming the category of type theories and about proving that is category is model category. That is nice. But can we go further from such category and classify type theories withing this category? Maybe by finding functor that assigns to each type theory some other mathematical structure that characterizes this type theory? My project is about finding the optimal neural networks for particular type theories and it would be nice to have some scan of them to formulate specific theorems.

@BenSteffan Your concern essentially is about "interestingness" in the mathematics. Grothendieck is called the master of definitions - so - the practicality is one aspect. For further outlook see (ages old) book https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4471-0147-5 - it is not so hard to come up with theories automatically, the most valuable part is to come up with interesting definitions and theories.

Sure, here's one example. Recall that a Boolean ring is a ring $B$ (necessarily commutative and of characteristic $2$) in which every element $b \in B$ is idempotent, $b^2 = b$. The category of Boolean rings is isomorphic (not just equivalent!) to the category of Boolean algebras; in Boolean algebra terms the addition is XOR and the multiplication is AND.
It's not hard to show that every finite Boolean ring is isomorphic to a finite direct product $\mathbb{F}_2^n$. However this is not true for infinite Boolean rings, and one might wonder for various reasons if it's possible to classify infinite Boolean rings.
The "answer," so to speak, is given by Stone's representation theorem. One way to state it in commutative-algebra terms is that if $B$ is a Boolean ring then $\text{Hom}(B, \mathbb{F}_2)$ is a topological space when equipped with the Zariski topology (it is in fact exactly the Zariski spectrum; so, every prime ideal is maximal and the quotient is always $\mathbb{F}_2$). This topology turns out to always be compact, Hausdorff, and totally disconnected, making this space a Stone space. This gives a contravariant functor
$$\text{Bool}^{op} \ni B \mapsto \text{Hom}(B, \mathbb{F}_2) \in \text{Stone}$$
and Stone's representation theorem asserts that this is a contravariant equivalence of categories; that is, Boolean rings are "classified" by Stone spaces. For example:

If $B = \mathbb{F}_2^X$ is an infinite product indexed by an infinite set $X$ then $\text{Hom}(B, \mathbb{F}_2)$ is the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta X$; arguably this is the simplest and least technical construction of the Stone-Cech compactification.
If $B = \mathbb{F}_2[X]$ is the free Boolean ring on an infinite set $X$ (not to be confused with a polynomial ring) then $\text{Hom}(B, \mathbb{F}_2)$ is the product $\{ 0, 1 \}^X$; in particular, if $X$ is countable this is a Cantor space. In this case $B$ is a special Boolean ring known as the countable atomless Boolean algebra.

A version of this theorem can be obtained from category-theoretic considerations as follows. For general categorical reasons (true for models of any Lawvere theory, e.g. groups, rings, modules) $\text{Bool}$ is the ind-category of the category of finitely presented Boolean rings, and this is equivalent to being finite, so we get an equivalence
$$\text{Bool} \cong \text{Ind}(\text{FinBool}).$$
Now, it's not only true that every finite Boolean ring is isomorphic to a finite direct product of copies of $\mathbb{F}_2$, but also that on finite Boolean rings the assignment $B \mapsto \text{Hom}(B, \mathbb{F}_2)$ produces a contravariant equivalence
$$\text{FinBool}^{op} \ni B \mapsto \text{Hom}(B, \mathbb{F}_2) \in \text{FinSet}$$
between $\text{FinBool}^{op}$ and the category of finite sets; this is the finite special case of Stone's theorem and it is easier than the general case. But now this gives
$$\text{Bool}^{op} \cong \text{Pro}(\text{FinBool}^{op}) \cong \text{Pro}(\text{FinSet})$$
showing that $\text{Bool}^{op}$ is, for formal reasons, equivalent to the category of profinite sets (the pro-category of the category of finite sets). This category turns out to be equivalent to the category of Stone spaces.
So, in other words, modulo showing that profinite sets are equivalent to Stone spaces, general category theory allows us to deduce the general case of Stone's representation theorem from the finite case. We can also switch the inds and the pros here, obtaining another formal result: $\text{Set}^{op}$ is equivalent to the category of profinite Boolean rings!
